# How to get modified value of TextBox

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

This is PageLoad code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //DropDownList Binding through bussiness logic
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_U, "SHORT_DESC", "UNIT_CODE", "UNIT_SOURCE");
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_Branch, "TYPE_DESC", "TYPE_CODE", "BRANCH_SOURCE");
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
            {
                string fileNo = Request.QueryString["File"].ToString();
                Bussiness_logic.OpenConnection();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("LINK_DATA", Bussiness_logic.con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE", fileNo);
                SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (dtr.HasRows)
                {
                    dtr.Read();
                    {
                        TxtFile.Text = dtr["FILE_NO"].ToString();
                        DDL_Branch.SelectedValue = dtr["TYPE_DESC"].ToString();
                        TxtSub.Text = dtr["SUBJECT"].ToString();
                        DDL_U.SelectedValue = dtr["SHORT_DESC"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                Bussiness_logic.CloseConnection();
                Label1.Text = "";
            }
    }
```

I have get value of QueryString from another page and file my fields according to **File** variable fetching data from database corresponding to **File** data .Fields(Two Textbox and two DropDwnList) are filling correctly but when i modify data in textbox or DDL and Click on Update button then it is not updating data . 
Update Button code

```
 protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bussiness_logic.OpenConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE_DATA",Bussiness_logic.con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE_NO", TxtFile.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB",TxtSub.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNIT",DDL_U.SelectedValue);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRANCH",DDL_Branch.SelectedValue);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "Action perfomed successfully !!!";
        Bussiness_logic.CloseConnection();
        Bussiness_logic.Empty_Control(TxtFile, TxtSub, DDL_U, DDL_Branch);
        //GridView1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //DropDownList Binding through bussiness logic
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_U, "SHORT_DESC", "UNIT_CODE", "UNIT_SOURCE");
            Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_Branch, "TYPE_DESC", "TYPE_CODE", "BRANCH_SOURCE");

        if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
            {
                string fileNo = Request.QueryString["File"].ToString();
                Bussiness_logic.OpenConnection();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("LINK_DATA", Bussiness_logic.con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE", fileNo);
                SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (dtr.HasRows)
                {
                    dtr.Read();
                    {
                        TxtFile.Text = dtr["FILE_NO"].ToString();
                        DDL_Branch.SelectedValue = dtr["TYPE_DESC"].ToString();
                        TxtSub.Text = dtr["SUBJECT"].ToString();
                        DDL_U.SelectedValue = dtr["SHORT_DESC"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                Bussiness_logic.CloseConnection();
                Label1.Text = "";
            }
         }
    }
```

Put Your second `if` also in first `if`.Because when you click update button than your page load event fire first.Means your textbox value again set from textbox.So putting your second if inside first if stop setting the textbox value from database on postbask,